# How to import jinja2.ext.loopcontrols to Flask correctly?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have read in Flask documentation that I should import the "jinja2.ext.loopcontrols" extension in order to use the range tag.

I'm trying to do so by:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.loopcontrols')
app.config.from_object(__name__)
```

But every time I use the range tag, it gives me:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'range'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.
```

Here's my code in the template file:

```
{% range number from 1 to 5 %}
 {% for x in posts %}
  <p>The value of X is: </p> {{ x }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endrange %}
```

So what's the correct way to import it?

Comment: What are you trying tu achieve?

Comment: @doru I was trying to just get the first 5 items from a list.. It works now with your answer, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you may use the `loopcontrols` extension:

```
{% for _ in range(1, 6) %}
    ....
```

However, if you want to get only the first 5 posts you could use a list slice (if your `posts` variable is a list):

```
{% for x in posts[:5] %}
    ....
```